# Is there any normed field such that the harmonic series converges?

Tags: convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

It is well known that the harmonic series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$$
is not convergent with standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. with $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.

Also the series does not converge in field of $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with $p$-adic absolute value $|\;|_p$ since
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}^p \frac{1}{n}\ne 0,$$
where by $\displaystyle{\lim^p}$ I mean taking limit according to $p$-adic absolute value $|\;|_p$.

Well, for any field $K$ of characteristic $0$,  $\mathbb{Q}$ (the field of rational numbers) is a subfield of $K$. Thus my question is:

> Is there any normed field $K$ such that the harmonic series converges?

Comment: Your norm on $K$ would induce a norm on $\mathbb{Q}$. The answer is then no, since by Ostrwski's theorem, all the norms on $\mathbb{Q}$ are equivalent to the standard absolute value or a $p$-adic one.

Comment: @GreginGre I thought so. Well what happens if we attach $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ to the field $\mathbb{Q}$? May I ask this in another post or edit this question to include the attachment question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Since all the partial sums $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N\frac 1n$ are in $\mathbb Q$, the harmonic series is Cauchy in a normed field $(K, \|\cdot\|)$ if and only if it is Cauchy in $(\mathbb Q, \|\cdot\|_\mathbb Q)$, where $\|\cdot\|_\mathbb Q$ is the restriction of the norm on $K$ to $\mathbb Q$. But by Ostrowski's theorem, the only norms on $\mathbb Q$ are the Euclidean one, the trivial one and the $p$-adic ones, in which the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: I thought so. Well what happens if we attach ∑1n to the field Q? May I ask this in another post or edit this question to include the attachment question?

Comment: @Qurultay I'm not sure that there is any well defined way of achieving that!